# Writing equations from Mathematica in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to use mathematical equations directly in Matlab. I found one thread describing about a built in Matlab file i.e. ToMatlab.m. I am able to download this file, however, I could n't able to set the path to make it work.

Regards,
Kiran

Answer (score 1):

You can install it via the File->Install menu. Details of how to do this are given in this Stack Overflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641512/how-to-install-new-packages-for-mathematica